# Adding a PHP textarea input section to a SQL query report

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a text area to my SQL query report, outputted in PHP.
The database contains applications for jobs with a drinks company, which are submitted through a form on the homepage. I want to add a Notes column, so that the managers can make a not of then they were called back, if they got the job and so on, for the benefit of other managers that use the system (so people aren't called twice, for example).

This is the Report code that I'm using at the moment, but I think I may have overlooked something. (Please excuse any incorrect indentations, I'm not too used to pasting code into this)

```
    <body>
    <?require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/incFunctions.php";

    opendb();
    function getTeamData() {
        $sql = "SELECT * from team WHERE t_preferredCity='Liverpool' order by t_id desc";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $teamData[] = $row;
        }
        return $teamData;
    }


    $teamApps = getTeamData();
    echo "<!--";
    //print_r($teamApps);
    echo "-->";
    ?>

    <table id="rounded-corner" width="100%">
      <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>D.O.B.</th>
        <th>Contact No.</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Preferred City</th>
        <th>Availabilty</th>
        <th style="width:70px;">Own Car?</th>
        <th>Previous Work</th>
  </tr>
<?
$i=0;
foreach($teamApps as  $teamApp) {
$i++;
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <?
    if (substr($teamApp["t_picture"],0,3)=="htt"){?>
    <a onclick="window.open(this.href);return false"href="<?=$teamApp["t_picture"]?>"><img style="width:100px;"src="<?=$teamApp["t_picture"]?>" alt="<?=$teamApp["t_name"]?>"/></a>
    <?}else{?>
    NO PHOTO
    <?}?>

    </td>
    <td><?=$teamApp["t_name"]?></td>
    <td><?=$teamApp["t_dob"]?></td>
    <td><a href="tel:<?=$teamApp["t_contact"]?>"><?=$teamApp["t_contact"]?></a></td>
    <td><a href="mailto:<?=$teamApp["t_email"]?>"><?=$teamApp["t_email"]?></a></td>
    <td><?=$teamApp["t_preferredCity"]?> </td>
    <td>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsMo"] ? "Mon," : "")?>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsTu"] ? "Tue," : "")?>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsWe"] ? "Wed," : "")?>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsTh"] ? "Thur," : "")?>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsFr"] ? "Fri," : "")?>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsSa"] ? "Sat," : "")?>
    <?=($teamApp["t_nightsSu"] ? "Sun" : "")?>


    </td>
    <td><?=($teamApp["t_ownCar"]==-1 ? "<span class=\"yes\">Yes</span>" : "<span class=\"no\">No</span>")?></td>
    <td><?=$teamApp["t_previousWork"]?></td>
    <td><form><textarea rows="5" cols="20"><?=$teamApp["t_notes"]?></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></td>
  </tr>

<?
}?>

</table>
<?
closedb();

?>
</body>
```

As you'll notice, I've started to add a form to the Notes column, but I'm almost certain that won't work, because I don't know how to tie make it add the text to the Notes column.

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I need to expand on anything.

Thanks :)

Comment: Textarea is `<textarea rows="5" cols="20"><?=$teamApp["t_notes"]?></textarea>` not `<input type="textarea" rows="5" cols="20"><?=$teamApp["t_notes"]?>`. Also, your `<form>` needs `action` and `method`

Comment: it is not <input type="textarea"> it is <textarea> tag.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Any suggestions on the SQL side of things?

Comment: When you update the notes column do you want it to overwrite any previous notes that where there or would the notes be additive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope, I got you right. Here are some snippets that may help you:

**Text-Input vs. Textarea**

The basic syntax of a text-input and a textarea:

```
# Text-Input 
<input type="text" name="t_notes" value="<?php echo $data_array["t_notes"]?>"/>

# Textarea
<textarea name="t_notes"><?php echo $data_array["t_notes"]?></textarea>
```

**HTML Form (form.php)**

A form for saving your data (add and edit). The "@" suppresses errors. So, there will be no error, if the $data_array is empty.

```
<form method="POST" action="save.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="t_id" value="<?php echo @$data_array["id"]?>"/>
    ... some inputs/textareas ...
    <textarea name="t_notes"><?php echo @$data_array["t_notes"]?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
<form>
```

**save.php**

A basic save script: INSERT (no ID set) or UPDATE (ID set). I really recommend using a Database-Class for handling stuff like this. Google for "PDO Class", "MySQL Class", "Database Class" - you'll find a lot!

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST)) {
    die("no data sent.");
}

$id = $_POST["t_id"];
if (is_numeric($id)) {
    // update, because the ID is numeric
    $sql = "UPDATE team SET t_notes = " . mysql_real_escape($_POST["t_notes"]) . " WHERE t_id = ". $id;
} else {
    // insert, because no ID was set
    $sql = "INSERT INTO team (t_notes) VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape($_POST["t_notes"]) ."')";
}

// die, if there was a mysql error
if (!mysql_query($sql))
    die ("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

**Avoiding the Echo-Shortcut**

You're using the echo-shortcut, that's not allowed by every default config. You could get in trouble, if you'll change your host. Since I got in trouble, I avoid it. It's a bit more to type but it could pay off!

```
Works everytime:
<?php echo $text?>

Shortcut, needs to be activated/allowed by your host:
<?=$text?>
```

Comment: Wow wow wow... Please don't use `@`, and surely not like that.

Comment: It's just a dummy. Why would you avoid the @?

Comment: Because you're avoiding the error instead of managing it. You could do a simple check like `echo !empty($data_array["id"]) ? $data_array["id"] : '';`

Comment: @Shikiryu Actually I agree: managing errors is a must! But in this case (the dummy) it's okay, I guess. Good to see different coding styles. :-)

Comment: 1. )
$id = $_POST["t_id"];
will result in a notice, if there is no post performed

2. )
From the table structure one can see that it's supposed to be 
$data_array["t_id"]

3. )
Inserting an dataset when its not present? Weird way of falling back and a potential security risk.

Comment: @mightyuhu it's just a dummy to give advices as easy as possible. code like this should never be live. security, architecture and performance would be too much for this question/answer - it's another chapter. i think you didn't get point 3. please read the code again and corrent me, if necessary. :-)

Comment: I did, i cant see the requirement to insert a record if there was no id given, however i find this disturbing.

Comment: @mightyuhu It INSERTS when there's no ID given, because the record doesn't exsist and has to be created. If the ID is given you will NOT INSERT, you will UPDATE. Or did you ever try to "INSERT ... WHERE id=$id"? :)

Comment: Yes but why would you want to insert something which was not there before, this is completely senseless to me in this context, furthermore it may be a security risk.

Comment: I think, I don't get you or you don't get me. You always INSERT something that isn't there before. If there would be something, you would choose UPDATE.

This Question was not about security, so I tried to keep my answer short to not confuse the Questioner. Of course there should be done more than just copy & paste, but I expect and require the Questioner to think out of the box.

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic: One day, $data_array will actually contain an integer or an object, and the app will crash with no error message, and the guy who is debugging it will have absolutely no idea what's going on, and he'll waste hours trying to figure it out...

Comment: @Denis That's why I mentioned, it's just a snippet... The author should know his syntax!

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic Obviously t_notes belongs to `team`. Since on the page there are teams listed I suspected the creation / deletion / whatnot of teams are dealth somewhere else, so since you insert into team, with no respect to the other values in this table etc. this is weird to me. I think the only thing the author wants to do here is to update the t_notes field.

Comment: @mightyuhu anyway, seems the questioner got what he wanted. we're  talking about incidentals, but thanks for your advice about the @-symbol! :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. ) You'd need a  field containing the id of the record or you can pass the id via a GET-Parameter in the form action uri
2. ) You need a php script that performs an update on the team table wrt. the passed id.

   ```
   <body>
   <?require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/incFunctions.php";

   opendb();
   function getTeamData() {
   $sql = "SELECT * from team WHERE t_preferredCity='Liverpool' order by t_id desc";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       $teamData[] = $row;
   }
   return $teamData;
   }

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $sql = "UPDATE team SET t_notes = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t_note'])."' WHERE  t_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t_id']);
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    echo "Note updated!";
   }



   //...

   <td>
      <form method='POST'>
      <input type="hidden" name="t_id" value="<?=$teamApp["t_id"]?>" />
      <textarea name="t_note" rows="5" cols="20"><?=$teamApp["t_notes"]?></textarea>                     
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
   ```

Comment: I got a `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` error on the line that begins with `$sql = "UPDATE team SET t_notes =` - still a bit of a newbie with this - any suggestions?

Comment: your missing a period after your first MySQL_real_escape.... $sql = "UPDATE team SET t_notes = '".mysql_real_escape($_POST['t_note'])."' WHERE  t_id = ".mysql_real_escape($_POST['t_id']);

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string`, `<form method='POST'>`